# How to configure logging for rabbitmq queue interactions on Windows

Tags: rabbitmq

We need detailed traces for queue interactions in order to be able to resolve current development issues.
How that could be achieved?

Comment: Timestamp and content of enqueued and dequeued messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. All that need to be done is bind another dummy queue to the same exchange poin and viola all messages get looged there and can be examined via management plug-in.